Screen not going blank or locking after specified interval
Following an upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS yesterday, my settings for the screen to dim and lock are no longer being honored.
OS: Ubuntu Linux 24.04.1 LTS; GNOME version: 46; Windowing system: X11
In Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Screen Lock, I have the following settings:

Blank Screen Delay: 8 minutes
Automatic Screen Lock: On
Automatic Screen Lock Delay: Screen Turns Off
Lock Screen Notifications: On
Lock Screen on Suspend: On

Following the guidance at Screen lock not working in Ubuntu 22.04, I have set the following:
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
However, my screen still fails to go blank after the specified interval.  Consequently, it does not lock.  Please advise.
Update: This problem appears to have been resolved through no direct action of my own.  Upon log on I had been receiving notifications of the availability of updates to the "Intel Management Engine" and to "System Firmware."  These notifications said they were coming from "unknown App" which made me suspicious about performing the updates for at least a week.  Eventually I located the Ubuntu "Firmware Updater" App and saw that two apps, including the Intel Management Engine, needed updating.  I updated both, rebooted the machine and noticed that my screen was now going blank and locking after my specified time (8 minutes) of inactivity.  So the problem was apparently at a level deeper than that controlled by my Power Management Settings.
